# Is There any way to handle JSON in PowerBuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

Hello from a rookie who lives in china. My English is bad,so hope you can understand what I'm talking about. So , Here is my question , I want to find a way to handle 'JSON' datas in PowerBuilder with an efficient way. Such as using javascript or using DLLs ... I have written some codes to handle 'JSON'. It works,But I dont know , I feel it's unstable.

Answer (score 0):

There are JSON capabilities in the current version of PowerBuilder (2019).  I'm not sure of what you mean by 'handling JSON'.